# Get value of select and use this to display div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select with 2 options within:

```
<select id="type">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is display a hidden div when the option 2 is set.

So I need to grab the value from the select and if it equals 2, show the div.

My attempt with jQuery so far is as follows:

```
$('#type').on('change', function(){
    if(this.value == 2){
        ('#hiddendiv').show();
    }
})
```

I'm including jQuery, but nothing is happening.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You _should_ be getting an error in your console, because you omitted the `$` before `('#hiddendiv')` !

Comment: @A.V as he's using "loose equality" the use of `== 2` is fine.

Comment: NB: if the missing `$` is indeed the fault then answers saying so are not required - the question will be closed for just being a simple typo.

Comment: you might want to change the handler to `$('#hiddendiv').toggle(this.value == 2);` because if you change the option again you want to hide the `div` - no need for the `if` condition

Comment: really wishing I had closed before any answers had appeared, now...

Comment: I'd appreciate someone explaining why this question should be closed? I need an answer to this and it wasn't a simple typo? I took extra care to ensure it wasn't a bitty question too, it's quite straightforward with what I'm asking?

Comment: So the problem _isn't_ just the missing `$` sign?  All the tests below show that the code works when written like that.  Failing that, you either haven't included jQuery or you've not wrapped your code inside a `$(document).ready()` block.

Comment: That's what the problem was, wasn't wrapped in a ready block.

Comment: I did wonder - that's also an _incredibly_ common question asked here.   A quicker response to the suggestion about the `$` sign might have saved quite a few people some effort...

Comment: While I appreciate that, I was testing all the different solutions provided and trying to work out why theirs were working and mine wasn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart the obvious typo, I think the implementation should be as below because if you select the option 1 again you might want to hide the `div`

```js
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#type').on('change', function() {
    $('#hiddendiv').toggle(this.value == 2);
  })
})
```

```css
#hiddendiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<div id="hiddendiv">hiddendiv</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion, that was what I was going to do next! I still can't get it to work though, I can't understand. I've copied your answer directly, no errors in the console either!

Comment: @sark9012 that indicates that you've omitted to put your code inside a `$(document).ready()` callback.

Comment: @sark9012 also check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: @ArunPJohny I just said 2 comments above there were no console errors :)

Comment: @sark9012 and I said in the very first comment on the question that there should have been, but you took a relative age to confirm otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `$`. It works fine:

```js
$('#type').on('change', function(){
    if(this.value == 2){
        $('#hiddendiv').show(); // you are missing here $
    }
})
```

```css
#hiddendiv {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<div id="hiddendiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing a number of things.

Try this piece of code:

```
$(' #type ').on('change', function(){
   if( this.value == 2 ){
       $( '#hiddendiv' ).show();
   }
})
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xj2vbgw8/1/)

Comment: `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value` is a jQuery anti-pattern - the latter is actually preferred in most cases.